# Fetching data from database and Filter Results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I'm getting the first 50 records using this query. However, there is a flag named `read` in the same table, and I only want to return the first 50 records that are not `read` (i.e. `isread=false`). How can I achieve this? Can anybody give me ideas for the required query? I have tried using sub queries.

```
SELECT * FROM notification WHERE toUserId = 'email' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding an `AND` condition to your WHERE clause: `userID = 'email' AND flag = true`. This will only return users with true value for flag of which you can get the top 50 by your limit condition.

Comment: u did not got question dude.

Comment: Hehe, yes correct, read it again and i guess this time I got it. This is simple too, we would need a sub query. So it goes like select * from notification where your_primary_key IN (select your_primary_key FROM notification WHERE flag = true ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50);

Comment: wait a sec, this will return 50 records all the time. I will modify it shortly. However could you please try and check if this works?

Comment: i got my as before half and hour but ya still u can give ans let me cross check. :)

Comment: Here the ans Select * from (Select * from notification where toUserId = 'email' ORDER BY id Desc LIMIT 50)sum where isread=false;

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was unaware about the SUM key-word but now I know it. :)

Comment: u can use any of the Word there bcoz its not function its just that to give virtual name to virtual table that we creating..

Comment: Not sure why the question was edited, because now it states that you want the first 50records where isRead = false. In this case, the AND (userID = 'email' AND flag = true) condition will simply give the solution.

Comment: Ya Question was edited by someone but now i put it back with more specificity.

Comment: select * from MyTable where city in (select TOP 50 city from MyTable where IsCityClean = 'Yes' order by CITY) and CITY = 'Mumbai'. Here's one more way on how we can achieve a similar thing. :)

Comment: ya that is similler but i already solved it dude. but thanks for your idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to get the first 50 values regardless of the IsRead condition and then filter it, you can try this but I populated the query in Sql Server.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 50 * FROM notification) S WHERE toUserId = 'email' and isread=false
```

This should help. You can try the same technique in MySql.

Comment: ya i need that top 50 but ya i need to try that once let me try again

Comment: If it helps then you can make it as answer.

Comment: nope its still not correct ans i can vote it up +1 for your ans but its not desired ans and i have update ans in comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM notification WHERE toUserId = 'email' AND isread = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50;
```

should work, though it does depend on you using 0 for false and 1 (or anything else) for true.  If you have chosen the tinyint or BOOL type then this will usually work (note tinyint can be -9 to +9 so make sure you set 0 or 1 as your flags.

In my opinion, it is probably better to use the terms 1 and 0 rather than TRUE or FALSE (though this is a matter of aesthetics really) because the code is then more readily transferrable.  It also prevents lazy coding.

Comment: no u did not get question dude. its giving top 50 first top 50 but i dont want that i want first 50 that could be any record and from that top 50 i need ans which have isread==false.

Comment: Try the code - it should give you what you ask and it would do you no harm to try it.  If you dislike my aesthetic, either use FALSE where I have put 0 or substitute whatever you use to represent false.  Perhaps you might rephrase the question, supply a table schema or even some sample data?  perhaps a sqlfiddle?

Comment: yes bro i have tried that but what the thing is i need last 50 Records which is having email id as requirement. but your  query is giving all the records of it which i dont want. bcoz i need first 50 records as what it is true false doesnt matter but after that i need to filter form that 50 records not from whole table. u got that??